# Retrieve value and data attribute from a select on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem:
One html page, multiple select inputs with:

- same 6 options
- same class
- data attribute called "data-productId" with different values

When the user changes the value of one of the select input, I want to retrieve the selected value AND the attribute value.

Example:

```
<select class="form-control tbl-sel-input" data-productId="some_value">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

When a user changes the input... I need the new value and the data-productId.

I've tried a lot of things but nothing worked.
I don't think this is relevant but these select inputs are inside a dataTable table.

```
var selectInTbl = $("select.tbl-sel-input");
$(document).on('change', selectInTbl, function(){
            var attribute_value= $(this).data("productId");
            var input_value = $(this).val();
            alert(attribute_value + '- '+ input_value);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice for setting `data` attributes is to keep them lowercase and separate words with hyphens as needed. This is due to the way jQuery serialises them in its internal cache, and having capitalised letters can cause mis-matches when retrieving data from the generated cache object.

Also note that the delegated form of `on()` takes a string as its second parameter, not a jQuery object.

With that in mind, try this:

```js
$(document).on('change', "select.tbl-sel-input", function () {
    var attribute_value = $(this).data("product-id");
    var input_value = $(this).val();
    alert(attribute_value + ' - ' + input_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control tbl-sel-input" data-product-id="some_value">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just perfect... I think you sir have helped a lot of people just now =)

Comment: As soon as SO lets me, I will mark this as the right answer